Is there a JSON-LD schema.org markup for a product assigned to more than one category?
Is there a schema.org markup of JSON-LD type for a product that is assigned to several categories or to be more exact - the main category and two subcategories? Could you help me with some valid example?
For example,  a bedding set that is assigned to "Bedding sets" main category, and to "King size" subcategory and another sub one called "Silk" material.
Is this useful or necessary at all to define subcategories for a product in my markup? Or it should be enough to assign a product just to main category like "Bedding sets"?
I want to write a code that generates JSON LD markup for online shop cms but stuck with some questions among which also that one that I've described.

Yes, you can add several  categories "category":["category1","category2"]. Google and schema.org validators approve this markup.
